# Why does the server ssh public key not look like the key in client known hosts?

Tags: ssh

From my naive understanding of ssh, the server shares its public key ( `/etc/shh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` ) with the client, who then adds it to the list of known hosts ( `/user/.ssh/known_hosts` ). So, I would expect if I look in those two files to see a long identical string in both (the "key").
When I compare the text in these two files I can see a string in both which is the same at the beginning but then becomes different.
Why can't I see the same long string in both files (which I would assume is the key)?

Comment: Maybe the client only stores a hash where the server obviously would need the full key.

Comment: An OpenSSH server normally has 3-4 keys, of different types to support possibly varying clients, but a client normally gets and stores in known_hosts only one of them -- make sure you are comparing the host key for the type stated in the client file. PS: it's not `shh`, although I do sometimes wish it were quieter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For privacy.

With modern versions of OpenSSH, the `known_hosts` file on the client contains a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the server name (or IP address), rather than the name directly. The reason for only storing a hash is that if someone obtains a copy of this file (e.g. leaked backup), they can't discover which servers are recorded, i.e. they can't discover which sites you connected to. They can verify guesses, of course: that's unavoidable since the legitimate client must be able to do this.

The `ssh-keygen` utility has a few options to manipulate the `known_hosts` entries, but of course can't convert a hash to the non-hash format. You can set `HashKnownHosts no` in your client configuration (`~/.ssh/config`) to turn off hashing, then the entries will be in a format where the public key is clearly visible.

Comment: I've never seen a version of OpenSSH that hashes the keyblobs, only the servernames -- and that not by default (at least in upstream, an installation or distro might change the default).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it contains the same string. the server has:
`ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBLmw2JjbKMO5LXTcJ67et6TBZeLff1WghM6koKjiHGh+gBbZzHrhDj20MuTxTB1kaTYh7f9T2G/zmhVpFMyUUoQ=`

and the client has

`|1|some_base64|more_base64 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBLmw2JjbKMO5LXTcJ67et6TBZeLff1WghM6koKjiHGh+gBbZzHrhDj20MuTxTB1kaTYh7f9T2G/zmhVpFMyUUoQ=`.

`man sshd` says, in part:

> SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT
>
> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional), hostnames, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  The fields are separated by spaces.
>
> hostnames may be stored in a hashed form which hides host names and addresses should the file's contents be disclosed.  Hashed hostnames start with a ‘|’ character.
>
> Bits, exponent, and modulus are taken directly from the RSA host key; they can be obtained, for example, from /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub.  The optional comment field continues to the end of the line, and is not used.

Comment: For me they are not the same, only the first 19 characters are identical (of the string starting with "AAAAE2....").

Comment: can you decode the base64 and parse them according to this guide to see the difference? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42268/how-do-i-get-the-rsa-bit-length-with-the-pubkey-and-openssl/42272#42272

Comment: FYI: your key is elliptic curve, but you quoted a section of the man page about rsa. Is there a more applicable section to quote?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth actually that section of the manpage was and still is out of date. For SSH version 1, which is obsolete and broken and RSA only, .pub files and known_hosts and authorized_keys (all) used three decimal numbers. For v2 all use a string identifying the keytype/algorithm and a base64 blob, for RSA DSA several variants of ECDSA and ED255519 (although OpenSSH since 7.0 deprecates DSA). The authorized_keys format section of the manpage describes both v1 and v2 formats, but the known_hosts section doesn't.